# Java split line from text file based on length and putting it into a vector

Tags: java, vector, split, text-files

First of all,  I'm fairly new to Java so forgive me if this question sounds stupid. To explain my program, I need to create a 2d vector that stores information retrieved from a text file. So let's say I have a text file like this:

```
    12345    abcde   09876   mnbvc  
    8762121  hsggkqe 87201   hayib  
    5142     ayega   61      hsgwq
```

Every column has a fixed length. I know we can split string in java by using String Tokenizer but in this case we have more than one " ". So my question is does Java has something similar to String Tokenizer but for splitting string based on length. Is it possible for the method to do something like >9 and <15 to get the value in the middle?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Substrings should do the trick. Substrings give you a portion of the from a beginning index to an end index -1.

`String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

**Example**

Say `lineOneText` represents the text from the first line of your file.

```
String firstColumn = lineOneText.substring(0, 9) // this equals "    12345"
String secondColumn = lineOneText.substring(9, 15) // this equals "    abcde"
```

Comment: Your comment `// this equals "12345"` is incorrect. It *actually* equals `"    12345"`

Comment: Also, `lineOneText.split(" ")[0] should give you "12345"` is incorrect; it actually gives you `""`. In fact, almost nothing said in this answer is correct.

Comment: My bad - I didn't realize there were leading spaces. I edited my answer to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Forget column widths; split on *any number* of spaces:

```
String[] columns = line.trim().split(" +");
```

[`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))  takes a regular expression as its parameter, and `" +"` means "one or more spaces".

You need the call to `trim()` to strip off the leading spaces, otherwise you'd get a blank string as the first element returned.

Answer (score -1):

split the line use method `split(" ")` and we get a String array,then iterate the String array find the not empty string,code may be like this:

```
String line = "12345    abcde   09876   mnbvc";
String[] words = line.split(" ");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(4);
for (String word : words) {
    if (!word.isEmpty()) {
        list.add(word);
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: You don't need all that code. See the [easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63984923/256196).